Why is there a diaeresis on the E ending of "suraiguë"?
This is the first time I've seen a feminized adjective end with a tréma: suraigu becomes suraiguë. Why is that? Why isn't it just a normal e like every other French adjective that uses a feminizing e?

nope you've got me there

Short answer :  because you don't want to pronounce aiguë as egg.

and suraiguë as "Sir Egg" ;-)

@jlliagre That will be "Sir Un P'tit d'Un P'tit" to you, thank you very much for minding your manners.

https://www.academie-francaise.fr/sites/academie-francaise.fr/files/rectifications_1990.pdf It's all in there, which is not in the linked response.

@FrançoisJurain s'étonne aux Halles.
